"A giant tap of Welsh nostalgia"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe)

(choir practice, Phillip, the choirmaster; William, a chorister)

(Phillip speaking) 'There's disagreement over the words' origins, but it was probably written by the poet Hywel ab Einion.' William loves the effortless switch in Phillip's voice to Welsh pronunciation. 'We'll sing in Welsh. No solos. It's often sung by male voice choirs, a giant tap of Welsh nostalgia, and that's not a bad thing for a memorial service, but don't worry, I'll take care not to drown you.'
I take "a giant tap" to mean "a giant treasure trove" or "a (giant and) inexhaustible source" of Welsh nostalgia in this context. The following link might fortify this notion: link. Is this notion correct?

something that allows a supply of something such as money, information, or people to flow:

Banning organizations from giving contributions to individuals would turn off the tap of money >flowing to corrupt politicians.
The industry requires huge financial support and it looks as though the government is willing to turn on the tap.



If you turn on a tap, you get a flow of something. A giant tap would produce a heavy flow of something. Here, nostalgia. You are missing the metaphor.

In British English, a 'tap' is a kind of hand-operated valve for regulating the flow of a liquid, very often water in a house, but also beer in a bar or public house. In American English, I believe, 'faucet' may also be used. The writer is saying that when Welsh choirs sing, it releases a very strong flow of nostalgia in the listener, like opening a big tap would allow a big flow of water or other liquid.


"Turn off the tap" is also used in AmE but faucet is more common nowadays.

@TimR - we also talk about a 'fire hose' when we mean an overwhelming flow of information, I think?

tap is not just British English. I say turn off the tap all the time as in AmE speaker. I disagree that faucet is "more common".

I'm really puzzled why I can't see that picture I added in Google Chrome, my preferred browser, but I can see it if I load this page in Mozilla Firefox, Opera, or Bing browsers.

You won't find tap used in product descriptions, for example, where a kitchen or bathroom faucet is involved, and you wouldn't say to the manager of the local hardware store that you wanted to "buy a tap". The "tap" refers to the device-in-use, as it were, not to the device per se: turn on the tap, turn off the tap.

I solved it! I disabled a Google Chrome extension called 'Referer Control' [sic]. I installed it in a fit of anti-tracking paranoia.

@MichaelHarvey, here are two other uses of tap that are very common in American English: (1) Tap water is the only way we refer to water that comes directly from the tap (or faucet) and is used to distinguish that substance from, say, bottled water, for which one is likely to have to pay an arm and a leg. (2) The device one fastens to a keg of beer to allow access to its contents.

@PaulTanenbaum - also, in the UK, a 'tap' can be a whole bar or pub, like the Coronation Tap in Bristol. Not forgetting a rock band, Spın̈al Tap...

Connect a garden hose to the outside tap to put water back into the well, while washing down the inside of the well casing and the well itself. After you turn off the taps indoors, you should allow the system to sit for 24 hours. During this time, you cannot turn on any faucets in the home or you will need to start the process over again.  From a business in the state of Maryland, USA.  https://haguewaterofmd.com/how-to-protect-your-well-in-flood-prone-areas/
